# ASP.NET Where do I initialize a data structure prior to any controller actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my first time creating a website using Visual Studio and ASP.NET MVC4.
For the first page my users visit, I need my controller to take their information and add it to a list.  Is there a place where I can initialize a list from one of my models prior to any of the controllers firing?
Any tips/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand why you need to initialize it before the controller. why don't you just initialize in the action method. you need to explain more to get good answers

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to instantiate the list in the model's constructor.